# Why AWS billing dashboad bills my EC2 under Free Tier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

This is my first month in AWS. The chargeable resources I use EC2, EBS, EBS Snapshots, S3, CloudFront CDN, CloudWatch, CodeBuild and some extras.

My usage is under free tier for all of the resources. But for some reason I'm being billed only for my EC2 which you can see from the images.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NcAbkxT_pjnOYTjbQ5FlXRQXSw5ybuAj
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OGNZcLBYmhy88bYy2q_stHetnN7hh-wh

My initial thought was, may be they bill you first then they apply the free tier limits. In that case why my other resources are not billed?

Update :

[My AWS Cost Explorer](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vEgej0TFU2EQl-0j6ylU2NLMl11n5Tij) says the refund is not included as I suspected. This seems a bit relieving but still its not clear whether the refund is my Free tier quota or they are talking about some different refund.

More info :

Is my account eligible for free-tier? Yes as per [this email](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EyHOR5IbHh-r3W2eTP8hmGmv7LmJvLOv)

Only t2.micro is eligible for Free Tier. Am I using only those? [Yes](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RFrZV1wEREz4Ex8QpSXr-MAXgdxHKToF). Both my instances are t2.micro. And I always run only one at a any given time to stay under 750 hours monthly limit.

Comment: What type of EC2 instance are you using? Only t2.micro is eligible for the free tier.

Comment: Go into cost explorer and explore, grouping by usage type. Getting into cost explorer is from the account area, click cost explorer, then the "open cost explorer link", then when that window opens hit "cost explorer" top left again (it's really odd). You haven't given us enough information to let us help you.

Comment: Is this your first AWS account? Is the account confirmed as under the free tier? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/free-tier-eligibility.html

Comment: @jellycsc I'm using only t2.micro for both my instances (only one I use at a time to prevent exceeding monthly limits).

Comment: @Tim I get Free tier usage alerts in my email. Yesterday I got an email for exceeding 85% of my snapshot EBS free tier limit. So I think my account is eligible for free tier.

Comment: @Tim This is the screenshot of the email I got after registering aws account. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EyHOR5IbHh-r3W2eTP8hmGmv7LmJvLOv. So I guess my account is in free tier. 
Thanks for the AWS Cost explorer. Let me explore that

Comment: "EC2" covers many things. Update the question with the cost explorer breakdown, but once you look in there you'll probably find the answer yourself.

Comment: @Tim The cost explorer didn't give me much except this one clue "Refunds excluded". I updated the question with it.

Comment: From that screen you need to click "cost explorer" in the top left again - it's a really weird system. From there you can get to a screen where you can narrow down your date range and select "usage type" from a tab near the middle of the screen.